# Pandas Ascending Label

Tags: python, pandas

Sorry if this question has already been answered, I am having trouble discerning the error in the following code snippet

```py
for layer in set(df['i']):
    print(layer, end='\r')
    df.loc[df['i'] == layer, ['c']] += max_
    max_ = df.loc[df['i'] == layer, ['c']].max()+1
```

I have a dataset that consists of a layer ID and a cluster ID. Currently the cluster ID's are dependent on layer ID, I wish for the cluster ID to be independent. Before the following code snippet the last few layers have cluster values as follows;

```
{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109}
{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28}
```

Afterwards it changes to;

```
{49152, 49153, 49154, 49155, 49156, 49157, 49158, 49159, 49160, 49161, 49162, 49163, 49164, 49165, 49166, 49167, 49168, 49169, 49170, 49171, 49172, 49173, 49174, 49175, 49176, 49177, 49178, 49179, 49180, 49181, 49182, 49183, 49184, 49185, 49186, 49187, 49188, 49189, 49190, 49191, 49192, 49193, 49194, 49195, 49196, 49197, 49198, 49199, 49200, 49201, 49202, 49203, 49204, 49095, 49096, 49097, 49098, 49099, 49100, 49101, 49102, 49103, 49104, 49105, 49106, 49107, 49108, 49109, 49110, 49111, 49112, 49113, 49114, 49115, 49116, 49117, 49118, 49119, 49120, 49121, 49122, 49123, 49124, 49125, 49126, 49127, 49128, 49129, 49130, 49131, 49132, 49133, 49134, 49135, 49136, 49137, 49138, 49139, 49140, 49141, 49142, 49143, 49144, 49145, 49146, 49147, 49148, 49149, 49150, 49151}
{49205, 49206, 49207, 49208, 49209, 49210, 49211, 49212, 49213, 49214, 49215, 49216, 49217, 49218, 49219, 49220, 49221, 49222, 49223, 49224, 49225, 49226, 49227, 49228, 49229, 49230, 49231, 49232, 49233}
```

I don't understand why the data is no longer in numerical order.

Comment: The output being displayed is a `set` - and sets are unordered (as in mathematics), as the order is determined from the hash table.

Comment: Even if set is unordered, that should only change the order in which layers are processed not how they are processed. For example if layer 10 is first then all the cluster ID's in that layer should add max_ to themselves (which max_ starts at 0). max_ would then update to the new max value of cluster ID's and move on to the next layer. Regardless of the order layers are processed the order of cluster ID's should not change.

Answer (score 0):

Following on the comment of @S3DEV, you can either omit `set` entirely:

```
for layer in df['i']:
```

or, if the intention was to go through unique values in `df['i']`, you can do

```
for layer in df['i'].unique():
```

if this does not solve you problem then we need to see more details on your `df`

Comment: The intention is to go through each unique value in df['i'].

Comment: As for more details, df has 11 columns x, y, z, r, g, b, nx, ny, nz, i, c
Currently for "i" contains the layer ID and "c" contains cluster ID in incremental order. However the cluster ID's reset for each unique layer ID. The goal is to have each cluster have their own cluster ID independent of layer ID.